# Aborting a recursive subprogram in the middle

Tags: algorithm, recursion, ada

If I need to abort a recursive subprogram in the middle, what should I do?

1. Raise an exception and catch it outside the recursive subprogram.
2. Add a boolean parameter Exit_Right_Now to the recursive subprogram, which would make it to traverse back from the Nth level of recursion to the external calling subprogram.
3. Stop using explicit recursion and rewrite my algorithm without recursion.

Which of the above variants are viable and which are not?

Note that I am writing in Ada programming language. Because of some optimizations allowed by Ada RM about exceptions, I am not quite sure whether an exception will do the right thing, not "nullifying" some operations which are before the point of exception raising. Will Ada do the right thing?

Comment: Option 2 works pretty well, though with a decent compiler Option 1 should be faster in addition to being easier. I would consider Option 3 only if stack space could become an issue.

Comment: With regard to your last question, I don't think optimization will cause a problem.  The optimizations in 11.6 that have to do with exceptions are really only permissions involving _language-defined checks_ and won't affect an exception you `raise`.  Objects that need to be finalized will be finalized, in every invocation of the recursive subprogram.  If there is any specific code where you're concerned about the effects of optimization, please post it as a separate question.

Comment: There is one case though were raising the exception might not have the expected effect: "out" parameters, which are generally set on exit of the subprogram. So for instance if you have A as an out parameter, set it to 1, then raise an exception, the caller might not in effect see the value 1 in the actual parameter.

Comment: @manuBriot This is true if the parameter is passed by-copy, but not if passed by-reference (see RM 6.2).

Answer (score 2):

Not having any specific knowledge of Ada, apparently all approaches might work equally well; however, 3. might result in an implementation that is more difficult to understand. For evaluating 1. against 2., it might me interesting whether the case in which the execution is to be aborted is more a use-case or an error case. If early termination in the recursion is some flow of execution that is "normally to be expected", an exception might be considered abuse of a language feature.